# How to get field name of document using elastic nest framework?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a document type in my c# application

```
[ElasticSearchType(RelationName="my-index")]
public class MyIndex{

    [Text(Name="id")]
    public string Id {get; set;}


    [Text(Name="name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

}
```

So I want to get the name of the document fields like  "id" and "name" using Infer.Field type.

```
var name = Nest.Infer.Field<MyIndex>(p=>p.Name);  // should return "name"
```

But I coudl not get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FieldResolver to get field name.

```
var fieldResolver = new FieldResolver(connectionSettings);
var field = Nest.Infer.Field<MyIndex>(p => p.Name);  
var fieldName = fieldResolver.Resolve(field);// should return "name"
```